# cordova 4.0 cli Could not find plugin info

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova project that I built with 3.4

upgraded to 4.0

now i get this error

```
Error: Could not find plugin info in /Users/derek / manualtaxpocket / taxpocket /
    plugins / .idea
at new PluginInfo(/usr/local / lib / node_modules / cordova / node_modules /
    cordova - lib / src / PluginInfo.js: 229: 15)
at / usr / local / lib / node_modules / cordova / node_modules / cordova - lib /
    src / hooks / scriptsFinder.js: 149: 25
at Array.forEach(native)
at getAllPluginsHookScriptFiles(/usr/local / lib / node_modules / cordova /
    node_modules / cordova - lib / src / hooks / scriptsFinder.js: 144: 26)
at getPluginsHookScripts(/usr/local / lib / node_modules / cordova /
    node_modules / cordova - lib / src / hooks / scriptsFinder.js: 79: 12)
at Object.module.exports.getHookScripts(/usr/local / lib / node_modules /
    cordova / node_modules / cordova - lib / src / hooks / scriptsFinder.js: 43:
    21)
at / usr / local / lib / node_modules / cordova / node_modules / cordova - lib /
    src / hooks / HooksRunner.js: 56: 37
at _fulfilled(/usr/local / lib / node_modules / cordova / node_modules /
    cordova - lib / node_modules / q / q.js: 798: 54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done(/usr/local / lib / node_modules / cordova /
    node_modules / cordova - lib / node_modules / q / q.js: 827: 30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch(/usr/local / lib / node_modules / cordova /
    node_modules / cordova - lib / node_modules / q / q.js: 760: 13)
```

Comment: cordova 4.0? the latest cordova is 3.6 rite?

Comment: They just released 4.0

Answer (score 2):

i just found the same error on my project in phonegap. The problem is one of the plugins you have installed does not have the plugin.xml, what is the plugin's info file. I fixed it with the following(it is not the definitve solution, but it is going to help you to install others plugins). Take the plugin.xml file from the any other plugin and put it in the root of the plugin you have the problem, and the next time cordova verifies your plugins, it won't find any error. I hope this solution can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the plugin by:

```
cordova plugin remove [plugin name]
cordova plugin add [plugin name]
```

That helped me.